# How to wrap a range of hex data with quotation mark?

Tags: excel, format, excel-2010, cell

I want to wrap a hex number with quotation mark as I hit the enter.

```
12bc >> '12bc'
```

I used such a format type: `'#'`, but it works only for numbers, not the a combination of numbers and alphabets containing a hex string.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer, courtesy @lori_m:

> Try this: '@'